# How to prove or disprove claims of existence of certain laws?

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently i asked [Did Australia ban small-breasts pornography?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/15790/5132). I'm interested, how should rumors about laws in different countries should be proved or disproved? What is the recommended method for a person, who is not a lawyer? Are there authoritative sources for dealing with these kind of claims?

Answer (score 4):

Proof is easy: Somebody could just point to the particular statute or regulation from which the law arises.

Disproof is harder: You would need to take somebody's word that they have examined sufficiently, or are experienced enough with, Australian statues and regulations that they can confirm such a law does not exist. I think the strongest disproof would be a quote from a reliable third party source (law journal, news organization with a reputation for accuracy and fact-checking, for example) that says the claim is false.

Comment: Disproof can also come about due to case law but that sometimes requires a bit more digging and knowing where to dig.

Comment: @RobZ Good point. You could count case law as probably the most reliable third party source :)